# Get how mant <li> under <ul> using Puppeteer

Tags: javascript, automated-tests, puppeteer

I have the following code:

```
it('7.1.8 - In Platform admin could review all ongoing and published notifications', async () => {
    const allNotificationList = await page.waitForXPath(
      '//header[contains(@class,"ant-layout-header")]//ul[contains(@class,"Notifications_banner-notifications")]',
    );
    expect(allNotificationList.length).not.toBe(0);
  });
```

allNotificationList gets the ul tag and I want to check how many li tag are under the selected ul tag.

Does anyone knows how to achieve this using Puppetter?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `page.$x` (or `someElement.$x`) to return an `ElementHandle[]` (`page.waitForXPath` returns a single `ElementHandle`):

```js
const allNotificationList = await page.$x(
  '//header[contains(@class,"ant-layout-header")]//ul[contains(@class,"Notifications_banner-notifications")]',
);
expect(allNotificationList.length).not.toBe(0);
```

I don't think it actually waits for the elements though, so you might want to add the following line first:

```js
await page.waitForXPath(
  '//header[contains(@class,"ant-layout-header")]//ul[contains(@class,"Notifications_banner-notifications")]',
);
```

Comment: yes, but `$x` returns `ElementHandle[]`, that is to say an ARRAY of `ElementHandle` (see https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v13.1.2&show=api-pagexexpression)

Answer (score 0):

I have no solution for this with Xpath, but if you are open to shape the Xpath to CSS selector, then the following will do what you need. Using [`childElementCount`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/childElementCount).

```js
const selector = 'header.ant-layout-header * ul.Notifications_banner-notifications'
const childCount = await page.$eval(selector, el => el.childElementCount)
expect(childCount).toBeGreaterThan(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(await page.$$('.Notifications_banner-notifications li')).length
```

Comment: pguardiario, while this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post.